# kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: User is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, celery, celery-task

I have django 1.11.5 app with celery 4.1.0 and I recived all the time:

```
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: <User: testuser> is not JSON serializable
```

my settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Makassar'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {}
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@task(serializer='json')
def task_number_one():
    user = User.objects.create(username="testuser", email="test@test.com", password="pass")
    return user
```

I call task in the view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    task_number_one.delay()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: This error also occurs when passing an object to a task from a view. See MrName's answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is because of Celery expecting a `JSON` data from your task function while you returned a `User` instance.

**How to solve this ?**
You are not using that return data anywhere, so you don't have to return it. That is you can remove `return user` from the task function.
Or,
return a `Json` data from the task function will solve this issue as well
**Solution 1**

```
@task(serializer='json')
def task_number_one():
    user = User.objects.create(username="testuser", email="test@test.com", password="pass")
```

**Solution 2**

```
@task(serializer='json')

def task_number_one():
    user = User.objects.create(username="testuser", email="test@test.com", password="pass")
    # return some json data instead of `USER` instance
    return {"status": True}  # Change is here
```

Answer (score 40):

This is because you are using the JSON serializer for task serialization (as indicated by the setting `CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'`), but you are trying to return a model instance (which cannot be serialized into JSON).

You have two options:

1) Don't pass the instance, pass the primary key of the instance and then look up the object inside your task.

2) Use the `pickle` task serializer instead. This will allow you to pass objects as arguments to your tasks and return them, but comes with it's own [security concerns](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#serializers).

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. In point 1, you mean something like this (with pk): `get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])`?

Comment: @MrName from **Celery 4.0** onwards they are using `json` as the default serializer, see [this change log](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#json-is-now-the-default-serializer)

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. As @JerinPeterGeorge pointed out, the error is coming from your RETURN value as opposed to the arguments being passed into your task. His answer is completely correct UNLESS you (for some reason) need to actually return the user object as the result (this is probably not the case). in this case, you would need to set `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'`

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I have the exact same issue.

Comment: The answer is correct for an almost similar situation(when trying to pass objects or class instances as arguments in a task) but not for the question asked. For the question, @JPG is right

Answer (score 1):

For the following configuration:

1. Django==3.0.11
2. redis==2.10.6
3. celery==4.0.0
4. kombu==4.0.0

I updated the following configuration on the settings.py file and it worked.

```
CELERY_SETTINGS = {
    'CELERY_TIMEZONE': TIME_ZONE,
    'CELERY_ENABLE_UTC': True,
    'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND': REDIS_URL,
    'CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT': True,
    'CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER': 'pickle',
    'CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER': 'pickle',
    'CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT': ['pickle', 'json'],
}
```

**Don't forget to update the actual value of TIME_ZONE and REDIS_URL**

The reason could be the Celery 4 version uses JSON as the serializer by default, while the celery3 version uses Pickle by default.

The old Django may not be expecting the JSON format from the tasks.
So, If you are using the very old Django version, this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

My celery task:

```
response = {}
...
except HTTPError as e:
        response.update(
            {
                'status': False,
                'code': e.status_code,
                'error': e.body,
            },
        )
    ...
return response
```

I had `EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable')` and `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError` although the response is a `dict` that shouldn't be a problem when JSON encoding.

It turned out that `e.body` is of type bytes. I changed to `e.body.decode('utf-8')` and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer not related to this question but also useful

if you pass obj to task, may got the same error info, then you can:

```py
@shared_task(serializer="pickle")
def email_send_task(msg: EmailMultiAlternatives):
    try:
        msg.send()
    except (smtplib.SMTPException, TimeoutError) as e:
        return f"Email failed with {e}"
```

Comment: its working thanks dude, that can help to accepting instance instead of json format arguments