# How to pass function as an argument to a celery task?

Tags: python, celery, pickle, marshalling, kombu

I want to pass a function as a parameter to a celery task. I found two similar questions in stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668657/pass-client-side-function-to-celery-task) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-cod)). I tried the solutions mentioned in the answers, and this is what I'm currently doing:

Inside caller module:

```
import marshal

def function_to_be_passed:
    # ...

serialized_func_code = marshal.dumps(function_to_be_passed.__code__)
celery_task.delay(serialized_func_code)
```

And inside the celery task, I'm deserializing and calling the function:

```
import marshal, types
from celery.task import task

@task()
def celery_task(serialized_func_code):
    code = marshal.loads(serialized_func_code)
    func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "some_func_name")

    # calling the deserialized function
    func()
```

However, upon calling `celery_task.delay(serialized_func_code)`, I get an error:

> kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in
> position 0: invalid continuation byte

Sharing stack trace below:

```
File “...caller.py",
 celery_task.delay(
File "/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 426, in delay
  return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 555, in apply_async
  content_type, content_encoding, data = serialization.dumps(
File "/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
  payload = encoder(data)
File "/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
  self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
  reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/python3.8/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 194, in reraise
  raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
  yield
File "/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
  payload = encoder(data)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 69, in dumps
  return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
File "/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 398, in dumps
  return cls(
File "/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 296, in encode
  chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 378, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Similar error occurs when I use `dumps` and `loads` provided by **pickle**.

> kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in
> position 0: invalid start byte

I'm using Django version 2.2.17 and Python version **3.8.5**.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373825/kombu-exceptions-encodeerror-user-is-not-json-serializable). In summary, you can change the task serializer to pickle instead of json as mentioned [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=serializer#std-setting-task_serializer). Be careful to not pickle anything from external resources, as it can be dangerous.